# Selectively updating (and not updating) fields

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to tell EF 4.3+ not to update some fields?

We have a standard in the DB where each table has a 'CreatedBy' column.  I would like to make sure that it is impossible to update that column.

The safest I see it would be to tell EF not to map the corresponding properties but just for the update.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first you can use the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute to configure the property as `Computed`.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hum...  Let me add a precision.  I want it to be pushed to the DB on creation (insert) but not on update.